# Request Dispatcher causing $.get of jQuery to alert the text of the page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets, get

for example :

i have a js like :

```
$.get('Test_Controller.html',function(response){ 
   alert(response);
});
```

and in my `Test_Controller.html` servlet i have :

```
    request.setAttribute("test","testData");
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher =
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp");
    requestDispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

Question is :

why is that the `response` will always alert the text content of the `test.jsp` and not the `JSON` that i passed through the `getWriter()`

**EDIT :**

I need to get the :

```
  TestData testData = new TestData();
     request.setAttribute("test",testData);
```

using jQuery's $.get() so the page won't reload, but unfortunately when i didn't do dispatch my response object seems to be null and when i do dispatch and forward, when i alert the response it alerts the text of the page.

Comment: Why would you prepare a response then forward to another page? Isn't the response ready after you wrote the json in it? If you do require to call `test.jsp` as well, why not generate the json from inside  `test.jsp`?

Comment: Please do check my updated question for clarification. thanks

Comment: after your edit, I don't see any mention of the json anymore. Are you writing the JSON from inside the JSP now? Please clarify. Anyway to get the request.setAttribute() stuff, can't you pass that as url parameters? Like for instance `$.get('Test_Controller.html?test=testData')`

Comment: @geert3 just to be clear `test` is not a variable from jsp.. it is  K,V pair from servlet which, in this case, happens to be a String that has value `"testData"`

Comment: `request.setAttribute("test","testData");` is not going to send anything to the response. I think you should read up a bit on the general concepts of request/response. Please see my answer below and try that. Should work as-is.

Comment: `TestData testData = new TestData();` creates a `JSON`..?!

Answer (score 6):

You want to write some information from within your servlet back to the client.
Your serlvet could look like this:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    Writer w = response.getWriter();
    w.append("... your json here ....");
}
```

And that's all there is (obviously wiring the servlet to your URL in `web.xml`). Your `$.get()` should see whatever you write into the writer.

Note that both what's sent (in Java) and what's received (in Javascript) are TEXT strings. You're responsible to convert your data to readable JSON on the Java side, and to interpret the text as JSON on the Javascript side. The latter can be done like this:

```
$.get(....., function(data) {
    try {
        // convert the text to JSON
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Problem reading data: "+e);
    }
    ... use the JSON data ...
}
```

Comment: when using `w.append()` can i put an Object inside the `append()`? for example an `testData` which contains many attributes?

Comment: No, the writer requires `String`s (`CharSequence`s to be precise). There are likely many utitlity classes out there (or even in Java API) to convert whatever name/value type you have (HashMap? Properties?) into readable JSON.

Comment: see my clarifications in the main answer

Comment: had any luck with this?

Answer (score 2):

In this case the final response is coming from test.jsp because you have forwarded the request to test.jsp inside that Test_Controller.html. If you want to print that json data to test.jsp then you don't need to forward that request to test.jsp page.Otherwise you can also create that json file inside 
test.jsp using scriplet tag like:

```
<% 
request.setAttribute("test","testData");
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String json = new Gson().toJson(test);
response.getWriter().write(json);
%>
```

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Hello, thanks for the clarification about the final response.. is there a way to pass the request attribute back to $.get()'s response without using JSON and dispatcher?

Comment: Yes.Inside Test_Controller.html we can write :

<input type="hidden" id="hid_id" name="hid_name" value="Here put your desired value">

I will suggest you to use jsp page instead of using html.In that case you can write inside Test_Controller.jsp:

<%
TestData testData = new TestData();
out.println(testData);
%>

Comment: Just to clarify.. the `Test_Contoller.html` is a mapped servlet. a .java class.

Comment: ok.Then in your Servelt we can write-
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException, ServletException
{
    TestData testData = new TestData();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(testData);
}

Answer (score -1):

Get the object in *test.jsp* .

```
<%
    TestData testData = (TestData) request.getAttribute("test");
    String testDataString = new GSON().toJson(testData);
    out.println(testDataString);
%>
```

*Javascipt*  USE **$.getJSON** instead of **$.get**

```
$.getJSON('Test_Controller.html',function(responseJSON){ 
   alert(responseJSON);
 var testData = responseJSON;// Then you can accesss your class values.

 $.each(testData,function(key,value){
      alert("Key:-"+key+": Value:-"+value");
  }  );

});
```